# Rotate image around the bottom?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

Say I have a clock and I would like to rotate the hour hand view to some hour, assuming its a `UIImageView`, where its bottom is exactly at the center of the screen,so rotate where the bottom is the anchor point, I do :

```
  hour.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
    let angle:CGFloat = (5.0 / 12.0) * (3.14 * 2.0);
    hour.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

But what happens is that it moves from his original position, and change the angle to something else.

I can't understand how you set the anchor point ? In relation to.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, you first have to set anchor , only then to set the frame of the view, if you first set a frame and then change the anchor, you get a wrong anchor.

So the code is :

```
        hour.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
        hour.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0-hourW/2.0, self.frame.size.height/2.0-hourH, hourW,hourH)
        self.addSubview(hour)



    hour.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
    let angle:CGFloat = (5.0 / 12.0) * (3.14 * 2.0);
    hour.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```